# Cannot find an initializer for type Double in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I would like to convert the String value I get from a text field into a Double value and store it but I keep getting the error that it cannot find an intializer for type Double that accepts an argument list type of (String). How do I fix this issue?

```
 @IBOutlett weak var tempText: UITextField! 
 @IBAction func convertBtn(sender: AnyObject){
     let t = Double(tempText.text!) 
     let temp = TempCoverterModel(temp:t!)
     tempText.text = String(temp.toCelsius())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `String` named `temp`, you should be able to use

```
(temp as NSString).doubleValue
```

to convert into a `Double` value.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `NSNumberFormater`:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
let t = formatter.numberFromString(tempText.text!)!.doubleValue
```